# How to open PDF file from Angular application

Tags: angular, pdf, routes

I am building an Angular app that use a PHP backend.
The process is:

- The front call a backend endpoint
- The backend builds a PDF file, store it in a specific folder, and returns the file URL (http://serverhost/tmp/somerandompath/somerandomname.pdf)
- The front opens a new tab pointing to the PDF file thanks to its URL

My problem is that the PDF url is intercepted by the Angular router and the user is redirected to the homepage (default behavior) instead of the PDF file.

Here is my (simplified) routing configuration:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'route1', component: Component1 },
  { path: 'route2', component: Component2 },
  { path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomepageComponent }
];
```

Do you have any idea how I can open the PDF file?

Thank you for your help,
Termos

Comment: Inaccurate question actually. The issue was due to a local configuration conflict between the angular host (localhost:4200) and another apache server (127.0.01:8080). Once both on the same server, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think your url from serve is not correct plz fix it first then
You can use this *** ng2-pdf-viewer *** package to render pdf in client side

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
          [render-text]="true"
          style="display: block;"
 ></pdf-viewer>
```

https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#readme

Comment: Hi Mohammad, SO was misunderstanding a special character in my original post so the URL was not appearing correctly. I have edited my original post.
Concerning the ng2-pdf-viewer, I would try first to go for an already "browser-made" solution as all browsers now support PDFs and offer options as save/print/etc... So, I thi